# Is there a faster way to, with the youtube_dl module in Python, check if a video is unavailable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I've been working on a personal music bot for my friends' server, and while everything is working fine, if it has to return a list of options to choose from it takes a good while (~10 seconds, which doesn't sound like a lot but it's a while as far as commands go) to check each URL for an error before adding it to the options list, and sending the menu.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
# note: spyt is the list returned by the search function

for i in spyt:
    title=spyt[i]['title']
    url=spyt[i]['url']
    try:
        ytdl.extract_info(url,download=False)
    except yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError as e:
        # Skip unavailable videos
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    embed.add_field(name=f'{i+1}. {title}',value=url,inline=False)
```

And I get this as an output whenever the code runs:

```
[youtube] hz7rLaYW1l0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] hz7rLaYW1l0: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] kLESxX6Q2Lg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] kLESxX6Q2Lg: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] k3xM4bX2Q_Y: Downloading webpage
[youtube] k3xM4bX2Q_Y: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] k3xM4bX2Q_Y: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] k3xM4bX2Q_Y: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] dC5Vorucvbo: Downloading webpage
[youtube] dC5Vorucvbo: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] dC5Vorucvbo: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] dC5Vorucvbo: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] NWemYtvndWg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NWemYtvndWg: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] NWemYtvndWg: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] NWemYtvndWg: Downloading MPD manifest
```

Is all of this downloading required? I feel like there must be a faster way to load just enough to check if it gets an unavailable video error or similar.

Comment: You could be doing a ton of those checks in parallel, I'd think...

Comment: You mean like threading? I've never really done anything like that, but it's certainly worth a shot. I'll look into it and see what happens.